# UI router empty parameters in URL

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am converting my application from using simple Angular router service to UI-Router. I have a route which has some parameters coming from search field. In the router service provided with Angular, if we search the empty input field the URL was redirected to the home page due to otherwise function but in UI-Router it goes to the this URL http://localhost:3000/#/resultPage//1.

I tried to use regex with the parameters but it didn't work. The code which I am using is mentioned bellow

```js
              $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

                .state("resultpage", {
                    url: "/resultPage/{searchParameter:[0-9a-zA-Z]+}/{pageParameter:[0-9]}",
                    templateUrl: "templates/resultpage.html",
                    controller: "resultController",

                })
```

How can I make sure that the URL get redirected to the home page if any of the paramters is omitted form URL?

Answer (score 0):

Pass variables instead of direct value.
For example, `url: "/resultPage/:paramOne/:paramTwo"`, here `paramOne` and `paramTwo` are the parameters that are being passed from `ui-sref`.
Now in controller add `$stateParams` to dependency injection to get url parameters.

```
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $stateParams, $state){
    if(!$stateParams.paramOne || !$stateParams.paramOne){
       $state.go('', {}); // redirecting to '/'
    }
})
```

now, it's time to set the state name from where you want to access.

ex:

```
<a ui-sref="resultPage( {paramOne: {searchParameter:[0-9a-zA-Z]+}, paramTwo: {pageParameter:[0-9]} })"
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried to use that code but Angular is giving me syntax error. Not sure what I am missing

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use query parameters instead for this use case. Check the first paragraph of the documentation here: https://ui-router.github.io/docs/0.3.1/#/api/ui.router.util.type:UrlMatcher

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by using query parameters. The link doesn't talk about my particular issue. Could you elaborate further?

Comment: Here's a better link: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing, scroll down to "query parameters" section. They're basically just less structured parameters you can use if you want URL matching to be less strict.